# Disable TouchableOpacity button after oneClick in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
export default decreasePrice extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    price : 50000
   }
 };
 _handlePrice = () => {
     this.setState({price : this.state.price - 2000});
 }
render() { 
    return( <div>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePrice} >
            <Text> Offer for you </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )
 }}
```

So , what I want is, I want to disable my button after oneclick once price is decresed , so that user can not decrese price again and again. I want to disable the button after oneCLick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use  a variable as flag, for example *this.pressed*:

```
export default decreasePrice extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.pressed = false;
        this.state = {
          price : 50000
      }
  };
    _handlePrice = () => {
        if (!this.pressed){
           this.pressed = true;
           this.setState({price : this.state.price - 2000});
        }
    }
    render() { 
        return( 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePrice} >
                <Text> Offer for you </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    }
}
```

in this way button just working for one time.
you alse can remove *TouchableOpacity* after press:

```
render() { 
    if (!this.pressed)
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handlePrice} >
                <Text> Offer for you </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    else
        return(
            <View>
                <Text> Offer for you </Text>
            </View>
        )
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro it helps.

Comment: @meysam This not worked for me. My code is like this. <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = { .5 } onPress={() => this.addMethod(names)} > <Text> Names </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind bringing in a library like underscore or lodash, you can wrap _handlePrice in `_.once()`. It removes the need for a separate piece of state inside the component instance.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { price: 50000 };
  this._handlePrice = _.once(this._handlePrice.bind(this));
}
```